# Added twig suggestion is not used

Tags: theming

I have added twig suggestion from .theme file to views__view.html.twig for customizing taxonomy.

```
   function mediumish_blog_theme_suggestions_views_view_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
      if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.taxonomy_term.canonical' && $tid = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('taxonomy_term')) {
       $term = Term::load($tid);
       $suggestions[] = 'views__view__taxonomy_term';
     }
   }
```

I am getting suggestion in twig suggestion display but when i am creating file and applying my custom theme, its not actually displaying output of that file, Its still using the default `views--view.html.twig`.